# Saving in $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex

When I save the following notebook code as $\LaTeX$,

```
In[1]:= DSolve[y'[x] + x y'[x]^2 == 1, y, x]

Out[1]= {{y -> 
   Function[{x}, 
    C[1] + 1/2 (-2 Sqrt[1 + 4 x] - 2 Log[1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 x]])]}, {y -> 
   Function[{x}, 
    C[1] + 1/2 (2 Sqrt[1 + 4 x] - 2 Log[1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 x]])]}}
```

I get this $\LaTeX$ code:

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{doublespace}
    \noindent\(\pmb{\text{DSolve}[y'[x]+x y'[x]{}^{\wedge}2==1,y,x]}\)
    \end{doublespace}
    \begin{doublespace}
    \noindent\(\left\{\left\{y\to \text{Function}\left[\{x\},C[1]+\frac{1}{2} \left(-2              
    \sqrt{1+4 x}-2 \text{Log}\left[1-\sqrt{1+4 x}\right]\right)\right]\right\},\left\{y\to
    \text{Function}\left[\{x\},C[1]+\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{1+4 x}-2
    \text{Log}\left[1+\sqrt{1+4 x}\right]\right)\right]\right\}\right\}\)
    \end{doublespace}
    \end{document}
```

I would like to have $$ instead of

```
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent
```

i.e., as an ordinary $\TeX$ file.

Comment: Cross posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48661/mathematica-notebook-saved) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/402544/having-an-ordinary-latex-file-saved)

Comment: Is it such a big deal to take the LaTeX code saved as shown and then just do a global search-and-replace in a text editor (or, if you prefer, define a Mathematica function to do the same thing upon the saved file?

Comment: Your link, unfortunately, appears to have died :-(

Answer (score 9):

The way you do this - by saving the whole notebook with un-formatted In/Out cells - will get you a file with non-traditional working *Mathematica* notation. For example you will get  square brackets for functions instead of round ones and capitalized functions names. If your goal is just to get a nicely formatted formula in $\TeX$ form, you could use this (for your 1st equation):

```
In[1]:= f = First[y /. DSolve[y'[x] + x y'[x]^2 == 1, y, x]];
        TeXForm[f[x]]

Out[1]//TeXForm=
c_1+\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 \sqrt{4 x+1}-2 \log \left(1-\sqrt{4 x+1}\right)\right)
```

If you paste the output in the body of your $\TeX$ file between `$$` you'll get a nice formula:

[image]

If you would like to save the whole document you need to apply some formatting to it, depending on what you exactly need. For example turning an output cell into text cell will result in wrapping the formulas in `\( ... \)` , which is an equivalent of `$...$` in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 4):

What I find convenient: in *Mathematica*

```
probi = Exp[Sum[-τ((Subscript[x,i,k] - Subscript[x,j,k])^2)/2,
        {i,j}∈Subscript[Edge,k]]] HoldForm[Sqrt[τ/(2Pi)]]^Subscript[N,i]

Export["formula1.tex", (HoldForm[logP[X,τ]] == Log[probi]//PowerExpand)//TeXForm, "text"]
```

and in $\LaTeX$:

```
$$ \input{formula1.tex} $$
```

This results with the formula:
$$\text{logP}(X,\tau )=\sum _{\{i,j\}\in \text{Edge}_k} \frac{1}{2} (-\tau ) \left(x_{i,k}-x_{j,k}\right){}^2+N_i \log \left(\sqrt{\frac{\tau }{2 \pi }}\right)$$

If the formula is large use *breqn*.

```
\begin{dmath}
\scriptstyle
\input{formula1.tex}
\end{dmath}`
```

Comment: Probably best to include in LaTeX preamble `\DeclareMathOperator{\logP}{logP}` and `\DeclareMathOperator{\Edge}{Edge}`, then change `\text{logP}` to `\logP` and change `\text{Edge}` to `\Edge'.